# Swift Combine .debounce memory leak?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, combine, debouncing

I think I've discovered a memory leak related to Swift Combine's debounce operator. 
It's either a leak, or I'm doing something very wrong. 
Here's a simple example that recreates the problem:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var currentValueLabel: UILabel!

    var numberSubject = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)
    var bag = [AnyCancellable]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupSubscription()
        bag.removeAll()
    }

    func setupSubscription() {
        numberSubject
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.currentValueLabel.text = "\($0)" }
            .store(in: &bag)
    }
}
```

The simple usage of the `debounce` operator seems to be causing a `malloc` leak(Checked using Memory Debugger):

[image: Leak with debounce]

Updating `setupSubscription()` to ditch the `debounce` seems to fix it:

```
    func setupSubscription() {
        numberPublisher
//        .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.currentValueLabel.text = "\($0)" }
            .store(in: &bag)
    }
```

If you run with this modification, and wait for the view to load, (aka for the subscription to happen and then for it to be removed from the array) you will notice that the leak is no longer there.
The leak is magically gone.

Could someone tell me if I'm doing something horribly wrong? This looks like a bug to me.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you see that it's a leak? I just see that there's a 16 byte object, not necessarily leaked

Comment: Well, since I’m removing all the subscriptions from the bag array, they should be deallocated. Other than that if you try and run the piece of code, and check with the Memory Debugger after the view has loaded, you should see that 16 byte object. The stack trace points to the sink closure. Removing the debounce operator, and running again, checking after the VC has loaded, the Memory graph will not show that 16 object. Also, Xcode marks it as a leak in the Runtime Issue navigator.

Comment: Is your breakpoint currently at line 30?

Comment: No Breakpoint. Ran the app, waited for the view to load, then pressed the issue navigator. Also ran it with Instuments, and it acknowledged it as a leak.

Answer (score 2):

Memory management in debug mode in the simulator tracked with the memory graph is not very real. I tried this with Instruments on a device, and I see one malloc leak of 16 bytes. In my opinion one shouldn't sweat the small stuff, and this is very small stuff. You can report it to Apple if you like but otherwise don't worry, be happy.

Comment: You're right, it might be negligible, but still, not right :)

Comment: I really do not like this approach, in my opinion you should always strive for a deeper and better understanding of the system/code you are writing/investigating

Answer (score 1):

First of all the Publisher will take up memory for as long as it's alive, thats obvious.

if you are debugging, and you are in the screen which is initialising the sink then you are going to see the memory usage of it.

what you need to check is when you are leaving the screen if the memory usage still continue to live, and it will since you did not cancelled the AnyCancellable

what you need to always keep in mind is that when you are storing objects in "[AnyCancellable]" you also need to cancel() them when the job is finished, in your case you should implement the following:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
     for cancellable in bag { cancellable.cancel() }
}
```